# What is UTC Time

Tags: utc

Could you please tell me what is UTC time exactly...

I'm currently developing a web application and don't know how to display the correct time to my user...

What's the best solution for that?

Comment: UTC time exactly, can be explained by the good old wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time  But to display the correct UTC time to a user, we will need to know at minimum, what programming language you need it in.

Comment: in what language are you developing...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems duplicate but still, This might help you to solve your problem, Please let me know if it's duplicate I will delete this answer and you may delete your question, We should keep this place clean :)

[How to show a UTC time as local time in a webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764458/how-to-show-a-utc-time-as-local-time-in-a-webpage)

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for your link, it seems now that my question is not really useful :)

Comment: You didn't deleted nothing...

Answer (score 2):

Its basically a standard time that you can use that's universal.   It means you can record  when things happen  without worrying about the local time.

However, for it to be useful for display,  you have to convert the UTC time back to a local time.

Comment: Ok, What's local time?