# Format javascript current date and time

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I display a date/time in the user's locale format and time offset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85116/how-do-i-display-a-date-time-in-the-users-locale-format-and-time-offset)

Hi - simple question - I just want to take this:

```
document.getElementById("time").innerHTML= new Date();
```

and format it into something legible, like this:

```
May 18, 2011 7:45 AM
```

making sure it is localized to whomever might be seeing it. Currently, it prints out as this:

```
Wed May 18 2011 07:46:25 GMT-0400 (EDT)
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Not really sure why this question is deserving of a negative vote...

Comment: Not sure how this can be a bad thing if the responses bring up new information, such as Gary Green's plugin suggestion below. I did a search for this and the solutions either weren't clear to me, the examples were overly complex, or they didn't fit my exact scenario. Everyone has a different level of understand of things.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Look up the reference for

```
  Date.toLocaleString()

  Date.toLocaleDateString(), and 

  Date.toLocaleTimeString().
```

Comment: I tried this, but it still prints: Wed May 18 2011 08:09:12 GMT-0400 (EDT). I don't want all that GMT crap.

Comment: Just used the following: var d = new Date(); var dd = d.toDateString(); var dt = d.toTimeString(); document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = dd + " " + dt;

Answer (score 12):

[Steven Levithan's `dateFormat()`](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format) (only 1.2KB when minified and gziped!) should do just what you need.

#### Javascript

```
// Formatting in: May 18, 2011 7:45 AM
var formattedDate = new Date().format('mmm dd, yyyy h:mm TT');

document.getElementById("time").innerHTML= formattedDate;
```

Comment: That should read instead: var formattedDate = new Date().format('mmm dd, yyyy h:mm TT');

Comment: its not working :( :(