# javascript client date format

Tags: javascript, date, extjs

I had a problem on extjs date. Seem by default it using computer date to create a date. 
I don't check up my pc and post the date.Then i found it based on American

```
 M/d/yyyy.
```

After i change the system regional setting date to d-m-Y.Everthing work fine.
So anybody know how extjs get client  date format ?

```
e.g 'YYYY-mm-dd' or 'M/d/yyyy' .
```

Since i need to parse the format from extjs code to php to mysql date format.
I try to find stackoverflow and site but seem not found out,

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/85116/how-do-i-display-a-date-time-in-the-users-locale-format-and-time-offset

Comment: Are you using the format function built into extjs? http://senchafiddle.com/#aKkbK
http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.Date

Comment: ya suppose sissonb. since it's a datefield.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert date to String when transfer it so that you can set the date format by yourself.

Comment: a bit tricky since you cannot knew which date using format m-d-y or d-m-y.Both are logic on 1-12-2012 or 12-1-2012. unless create a class checking it was a valid date or not..

Comment: It is a data object, not a string, so you can convert it to the format string whatever you like.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the default format used is 'm/d/y', and you can change the format self, and I don't think so the ext can get the client date format and change the format consistently.

Answer (score 1):

dont mind your regional setting

you have two options
in your server you convert to string and change format

```
yourDate.ToString("MMM dd, yyyy")
```

see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) or [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) for standard and custom format

or in your extjs code you use

```
renderer: Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('d-M-Y'),
```

see [here](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.Date) for available format strings.

Comment: I knew it. but what if the A person like  d-m-y format and another person like  d/M/Y set in the computer regional setting.. Quite an issue though. I push the customer must use  d-m-Y.Sometimes they always mistake because they used up to old system.

Comment: i had the same issue since we have customers who use 31/12/2012 and those who use 12/31/2012..thats why i write the month in letter that would be: 31 Dec 2012, that is the only solution i have found for now.Another option is to add a setting in  ap for the user to choose his prefered format save it somewhere in a var timesetting and call it like this: Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer(timesetting),