# Mobile HTML5 App - determining a users date/time preferences?

Tags: javascript, html, date, cordova

Is there any way via HTML5, proprietary apis, or PhoneGap to obtain the date format a given user is likely to want?

I currently display everything as `MM/dd/yyyy`, but this is confusing for any users who live in `dd/MM/yyyy` countries.

Comment: via javascript since the question is tag with javascript. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/85116/how-do-i-display-a-date-time-in-the-users-locale-format-and-time-offset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you will want to look into the Globalization plugin's getDatePattern method.

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/Globalization
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/BlackBerry/Globalization
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/Globalization

Comment: I'm currently using PhoneGap build to avoid the hassle of building, so I hope this isn't the only solution. If it is, then I need to start begging the phonegap build guys to support this plugin. :P +1 regardless.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to determine the local day-month/month-day order is to check it.

You can check once and save it as a boolean to use in any input or output date formatting.

(this returns true if the date should precede the month- feel free to reverse it!).

```
Date.datefirst= (function(){
    return Date.parse('2/6/2009')> Date.parse('6/2/2009');
})()
```

Comment: Date.parse is locale dependent? If this works on phones, this is exactly what I need. I'll accept once I've confirmed.