# How to change Date format according to the country

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a requirement to change the order of DD/MM/YYYY tags according to a users country .

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country

The way that I was thinking to do this is to create a country / Dateformat table and according to the country selection to move the fields around using jquery .

Is there an existing way for this to be done in php or even in js or a better approach ?
I was also looking for a table of country/ dateformat rather than inserting all the values manually  but I couldn't find anything ...

Comment: Check out the term "locale".

Comment: Take a look at http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#localization and http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/Localization

Comment: Thanks for the answers everyone but I need a small example of code if possible to move the fields around using e.g the JS toLocaleString that was suggested , I have three select elements DD MM YYYY . The jquery example is good but it looks that you need to include a datepicker for each country.

Comment: By far the best solution is to use a single, unambiguous format (e.g. 10 March, 2013). If you attempt to "localise" the string, you will still get it wrong a good percentage of the time. Also, the implementation of `Date.prototype.toLocaleString` is implementation dependent, so you will still need to manually parse the date if you want to present it in a consistent format across all browsers (Some may do `Tuesday, 11 March 2013` and some may do `3/11/2013` and others `2013-03-11`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For PHP, this should be a good start: http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php

For JavaScript: [Display date/time in user's locale format and time offset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85116/how-do-i-display-a-date-time-in-the-users-locale-format-and-time-offset)

All in all, most modern languages have locale support built-in very well. You should not have to implement this yourself. It will be tiresome and buggy (localization is hard).

Answer (score 2):

if you use PHP then the IntlDateFormatter() helps you out:

```
$d = new DateTime();

$fmt = new IntlDateFormatter('en-US', IntlDateFormatter::SHORT, IntlDateFormatter::NONE);
echo "US: ".$fmt->format($d)."<br/>";

$fmt = new IntlDateFormatter('en-GB', IntlDateFormatter::SHORT, IntlDateFormatter::NONE);
echo "GB: ".$fmt->format($d)."<br/>";

$fmt = new IntlDateFormatter('en-AU', IntlDateFormatter::SHORT, IntlDateFormatter::NONE);
echo "AU: ".$fmt->format($d)."<br/>";

$fmt = new IntlDateFormatter('de-DE', IntlDateFormatter::SHORT, IntlDateFormatter::NONE);
echo "DE: ".$fmt->format($d)."<br/>";
```

Output:

```
US: 2/1/18
GB: 01/02/2018
AU: 1/2/18
DE: 01.02.18
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the format of a date on the client side, you can try the [toLocaleString](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tolocalestring.asp) function on the Date object in JavaScript.  The toLocaleString will change the format based on the client OS's settings for their location.  You also would not need to have a table with the country and date format.

This can be done without the need for jQuery or any additional plugin.

Comment: Good in theory but doesn't work in practice as not all browsers support it. Please don't reference W3Schools, [ECMA-262](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.5) the definitive reference for language features, the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) is also a good resource. In this case, [toLocaleDateString](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.6) is probably a better suggestion.