# javascript get timestamp in system timezone not in UTC

Tags: javascript, node.js, time

Hi all im looking for a way to get current system time in a timestamp.
i used this to get timestamp:

```
new Date().getTime();
```

but it return the time in UTC timezone not the timezone that server use

is there any way to get timestamp with system timezone?

Answer (score 19):

Check out moment.js http://momentjs.com/

```
npm install -S moment
```

New moment objects will by default have the system timezone offset.

```
var now = moment()
var formatted = now.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss Z')
console.log(formatted)
```

Comment: +1 - I've used Moment.js a ton and its a great piece of software to work with.

Answer (score 9):

Since getTime returns unformatted time in milliseconds since EPOCH, it's not supposed to be converted to time zones. Assuming you're looking for formatted output,

Here is a stock solution without external libraries, from an answer to [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85116/how-do-i-display-a-date-time-in-the-users-locale-format-and-time-offset):

> the various `toLocale…String` methods will provide localized output.
>
> ```
> d = new Date();
> alert(d);                        // -> Sat Feb 28 2004 23:45:26 GMT-0300 (BRT)
> alert(d.toLocaleString());       // -> Sat Feb 28 23:45:26 2004
> alert(d.toLocaleDateString());   // -> 02/28/2004
> alert(d.toLocaleTimeString());   // -> 23:45:26
> ```

And extra formatting options can be provided if needed.

- [**toLocaleString**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString)
- [**Various other Date functions you may want to use**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Answer (score 7):

Install the module 'moment' using:

```
npm install moment --save
```

And then in the code add the following lines -

```
var moment = require('moment');
var time = moment();
var time_format = time.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss Z');
console.log(time_format);
```