# Sql server how to get current date as per setting

Tags: sql-server

we know people set their date format like dd/MM/yyyy in their pc or may be MM/dd/yyyy. so i want to show date only according to system settings.

now i am doing this way

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),101) AS DateOnly;
```

if possible please help

Comment: This will work. what else you want?

Comment: Get it as a date, let the client format it as per their desired setting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it can be done the way you are trying to..

If the user is querying using a query tool, then there are settings in that query tool on how to display dates.

If you have an application layer (web, client, etc) you need to format it according to the locale somewhere.

This can be

a) in SQL on the SQL-Server as follows:

```
DECLARE @d DATETIME = '01/01/2011';
SELECT FORMAT ( @d, 'd', 'en-US' ) AS US_Result;
SELECT FORMAT ( @d, 'd', 'fr-FR' ) AS FR_Result;
SELECT FORMAT ( @d, 'd', 'de-DE' ) AS DE_Result;
```

(where the app passes the locale from the client through to the SQL)

b) in the app code .net/java using e.g. a Format class, etc.

```
public class FormatDate
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
      // Sets the CurrentCulture property to U.S. English.
      Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
      // Displays dt, formatted using the ShortDatePattern
      // and the CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.
      Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("d"));

      // Creates a CultureInfo for German in Germany.
      CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("de-DE");
      // Displays dt, formatted using the ShortDatePattern
      // and the CultureInfo.
      Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("d", ci));
   }
}
```

c) in the client e.g. if the user is looking at a web page you'll need to use e.g javascript as outlined here:

[Display date/time in user's locale format and time offset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85116/how-do-i-display-a-date-time-in-the-users-locale-format-and-time-offset)

Comment: FORMAT is SQL Server 2012+ only so may not apply here

Answer (score 3):

This can't be done in SQL Server. It doesn't know what a client's settings are.

You'd do this in the calling application or web server.

Comment: it can be done in SQL server if the client tells the server how it wants it as a query param

Comment: @MarkD: SQL Server does not have the full range of locale settings prior to FORMAT. Generally, it can't and you shouldn't

Comment: Sure @gbn you might be right on the "shouldn't" and "can't" but it might depend on his situation - we don't know anything about the app, and whether he has 2012, etc. the original question was how to do it in sql-server..