# Get local datetime format In Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get local machine datetime format in Jquery?
means if local date time format is in "MM-dd-yyyy" ,so this format I want to get in jquery. 
OR
How can I convert my any datetime in local datetime format in jquery?

Comment: Please post your code???

Comment: jquery does not deal with date time formats, for that you can look at date time libraries like [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/)

Comment: Did you try google it? Be sure you're not the first guy encounter with this problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I display a date/time in the user's locale format and time offset?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/85116/how-do-i-display-a-date-time-in-the-users-locale-format-and-time-offset)

Comment: @Arun actually i have one service which convert date according to dateformat which we have pass, so i want to get local datetime format so that i show date according to local date time format.

Answer (score 1):

You can change date format in jquery datepicker as such:

```
var date = $('#datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' }).val();
```

This [Link](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker#option-dateFormat) , [Link](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/formatDate) and [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328025/jquery-ui-datepicker-change-date-format) may be helpful.

Comment: `DatePicker`?? there is no word like datepicker in the Question.