# How to compare date in Javascript with locale

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp, date

Current application is implemented by JSP, so it will pass localized `Date` (in MM/DD/YYYY or DD/MM/YYYY depends on the locale) on the input field entered by user. Then javascript is supposed to identify that date and filter out data (i.e. orders that have been placed) on the UI with the same date.

Just like user enter a date(MM/DD/YYYY or DD/MM/YYYY depends on the locale)
then the list of orders on the UI should only remain the ones created on the same date
So basically, javascript need to fetch the date entered by user and dates from all orders, to make a compare.

code sample is like this

```
if(aOrder_date != null ){
    if(aOrder_date != '' &amp;&amp; aOrder_date != 'undefined'
        &amp;&amp; order_date.getTime() != aOrder_date.getTime()){
        showUp = false;
    }
}
```

So now the issue is, even JSP(Java) is on Spanish locale, but javascript still take it with English locale. then:

```
08/03/2013
```

on the input field is

```
March, 08, 2013 in Spanish Calendar
```

but it is interpreted as

```
Auguest, 03, 2013 in English Calendar
```

by javascript

Also javascript cannot identify any date after the `12th`(make sense as javascript twist `month` and `day`) when the page is switched to `Spanish`.

So is there anyway to put or sync locale in Javascript then make above working properly?

Comment: A `Date` object isn't localized - it's just a number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch. It's really unclear exactly where things are happening here, but it sounds like you should be simply converting the `Date` to a `String` using a fixed format.

Comment: @Jon Skeet Thanks but then how can I compare the two dates if they are on string type?

Comment: What do you mean by "on string type"? Your whole question is very confusing at the moment. Please edit it to clarify.

Comment: I suggest checking out the [moment.js library](http://momentjs.com/) which is built to help with stuff like this specifically [this bit on formatting](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/)

Comment: Since you haven't posted any code, I can only say: based on the locale chosen by user, have a `dateToUse` object that will be the string representation of your date, and apply a date formatting to your date always to `MM/dd/yyyy`.

Comment: Your input date is ambiguous.  You have to decide which input formats you accept based on the users locale. Maybe you need to allow the user to specify the locale they want to use, or use the browser's default based on the language/location. Then you use the same format when outputting the same date

Answer (score 1):

Hope this link may help you.

[Display date/time in user's locale format and time offset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85116/how-do-i-display-a-date-time-in-the-users-locale-format-and-time-offset)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString

or you can use this parsing methods for date.

```
  toISOString()
```

or

```
  getUTCDate(), getUTCMonth() and getUTCDay()
```

or

```
  dateString.toLocaleString()
```

Comment: I think the question is more about parsing the input

Answer (score 0):

You can use [datejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datejs). In the downloads you can find localized versions of datejs.

Note that the **active** locale can be **dynamically established** by code **instead of detected** by the browser's context via loading the different versions available (date-es-AR.js, date-en-GB.js, ...).

So finally you can use `Date.parse` with your established locale.