# How to convert a UTC time to local time

Tags: javascript, timezone

Hi I am delivering a UTC time from the server to the client's browser. The time shows up correctly but the timezone does not. Here is how the time is showing up:

> Tue Jul 15 2014 19:35:00 GMT-0500

The date and time are correct but the time zone is not. I just want to change the GMT -0500 to UTC. When I change it to UTC then I can convert it to local time.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/85116/how-do-i-display-a-date-time-in-the-users-locale-format-and-time-offset

Comment: If the time shows up correctly in the wrong timezone, then the original datetime is not correct. Parse it correctly as UTC, and use UTC output methods.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even though you're receiving a UTC time, the javascript object will always show up as the local time in the console. For example:

```
var date = new Date(1405458751062);
```

Outputs this for me:

```
Tue Jul 15 2014 17:12:31 GMT-0400
```

You have to take that date object and output the specific properties.

**For example in UTC:**

```
date.getUTCFullYear() + "-" + (date.getUTCMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getUTCDate() + " " + date.getUTCHours() + ":" + date.getUTCMinutes();
```

Outputs:

```
2014-7-15 21:12
```

**Or local time:**

```
date.getFullYear() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getDate() + " " + date.getHours() + ":" + date.getMinutes();
```

Outputs:

```
2014-7-15 17:12
```

To me it seems like you are parsing in your date incorrectly because 19:35 hasn't come around yet. You need to make sure your date is parsed correctly so that when you output the date object to the console (ex. `console.log(date)`), it will display the date in your browser's local time. From there you must format the date properly in UTC using a method similar to above.

---

I would suggest using [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com) though. It makes life easy:

```
var date = moment(1405458751062); 
date.toString();         // returns Tue Jul 15 2014 17:12:31 GMT-0400
date.utc().toString();   // returns Tue Jul 15 2014 21:12:31 GMT+0000
date.local().toString(); // returns Tue Jul 15 2014 17:12:31 GMT-0400
```

The library makes it very easy to format dates as well.

Comment: Careful.  If you go down the path of building the string from individual parts, you'll need to add 1 to the month fields, as the `Date` object uses months 0-11 instead of 1-12.  You might also want to zero-pad each field.  +1 for the moment.js solution though.

Comment: @MattJohnson Fixed. I forgot about that months were zero-indexed in javascript (probably because I've been formatting dates with moment.js for so long now haha)