# How to pass value of date variable from javascript to html

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I want to print the value of the date by passing it from the JavaScript file to the HTML file.

HTML file:

```
  <html> 
      <body> 
          <script src=background.js> </script> 
          <span id="showDate"> </span> 
      </body> 
  </html>
```

JavaScript file:

```
document.body.style.background = "url('1.jpg')";
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
if(dd<10) {
  dd='0'+dd
} 
if(mm<10) {
  mm='0'+mm
} 
today = dd+'/'+mm+'/'+yyyy;
alert(today);
document.getElementById("showDate").value=today;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I display a date/time in the user's locale format and time offset?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/85116/how-do-i-display-a-date-time-in-the-users-locale-format-and-time-offset)

Comment: use `textContent ` or `innerHTML` instead of `value`  in last line of your code

Comment: This has nothing to do with chrome extensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all link up your javascript file like into HTML file bottom part.

```
<script src="your_javascript_file.js"></script>
```

and then

Write Your js code into your js file with flowing line and pass inner html into

```
document.getElementById("showDate").innerHTML = today;
```

Comment: Worked when I linked javascript file at bottom instead of top. Thanks!
Can you explain?

Comment: @DeepKakkad HTML is parsed from top to bottom, so if the script runs at the top, the element that it's trying to access won't exist yet.

Comment: Now I get it. Thanks! @MaximillianLaumeister

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way:

```
 document.getElementById("showDate").textContent = today;
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, a little comment on how the code works might be able to help the OP even more.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use `textContent` instead of `value`.

**Live Working Demo:**

```js
document.body.style.background = "url('1.jpg')";
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
if (dd < 10) {
    dd = '0' + dd
}
if (mm < 10) {
    mm = '0' + mm
}
today = dd + '/' + mm + '/' + yyyy;
document.getElementById("showDate").textContent = today;
```

```html
<span id="showDate"> </span>
```

JSFiddle Version: https://jsfiddle.net/ae6wfz12/

Comment: Thanks. But, I'm working on a chrome extension and still not working with me.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to put the scripts that access document elements at the end of the body tag, so that they are executed only after the required elements are loaded.

```
 <html> 
      <body> 
          <span id="showDate"> </span> 
      </body> 
      <script src=background.js> </script>
  </html>
```

Secondly, as Maximillian told, use textConten or innerHTML or innerText property of the selected element to get or set the value.

`document.getElementById("showDate").innerHTML = '<strong>' + today '</strong>';`