# how can I create a new Date() in jquery with a value from my php script in a specific timezone?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datetime

I have a simple php script that returns time in a following format:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Tokyo');
echo (new DateTime())->format('F d, Y H:i:s O');
```

the output of it is:

```
October 01, 2015 18:34:35 +0900
```

Now I fetch this data in my jquery script and I want to create a new Date() object from this string. However, I don't know how to include the timezone there.
So far I'm doing like this:

```
var serverTime = "October 01, 2015 18:34:35 +0900";//fetched from server
var timezone = serverTime.substr(serverTime.length - 5);
var substractedDate = serverTime.substr(0, serverTime.length - 5);
var tokyoTime = new Date(substractedDate);
alert(tokyoTime);
```

but it shows me:

```
Thu Oct 01 2015 18:40:34 GMT+0200 (Central Europe Daylight Time)
```

How can I create a date like this:

```
Thu Oct 01 2015 18:40:34 GMT+0900 (Asian...)
```

?

Comment: Could it be because you alert the romeTime instead of the tokyoTime?

Comment: oh yeah sorry, I forgot to rename the variables for putting it here, now I fixed it here, the problem appears in tokyoTime of course :)

Comment: Cant test it since I dont have any php environment available. Have you tried  if it behaves different using the same Class? Because you use in the First example `DateTime` and in the second one `Date`.  You also could check if `date_default_timezone_get();` is correctly set right before you set tokyoTime.

Comment: Thanks, I assume the php works fine since it returns me `October 01, 2015 18:34:35 +0900`, the real question is how to include the timezone in creation of the date object in jquery...

Comment: Have you tried this plugin? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10087819/convert-date-to-another-timezone-in-javascript

Comment: @Zim84 I tried, but I need a date object later on and I cannot convert moment to date..

Comment: Next one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/85116/how-do-i-display-a-date-time-in-the-users-locale-format-and-time-offset

Answer (score 0):

use this code and customize your getDate function by `date_default_timezone_get()` to get server time zone:

```
var serverTime = "<?php echo (new DateTime())->format('F d, Y H:i:s O'); ?>";
```

or use TimezoneJS plugin:
Download TimezoneJS [from](https://github.com/mde/timezone-js).

And use it:

```
<?php date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Tokyo'); ?>
var dt = new timezoneJS.Date('<?php echo ?>', '<?php echo date_default_timezone_get();?>');
```