# HTML Date / Time Input Format 'yyyy-MM-dd' vs 'MM/dd/yyyy' Between Locales with Selenium / Capybara

Tags: javascript, selenium, capybara, selenium-chromedriver

Chrome / Selenium appears to have a different format for some input types between locales. For example, the date picker (i.e. `input type="date"`) for the is formatted as `mm/dd/yyyy` for US and `yyyy-mm-dd` for Canada. This makes it difficult to write specs that work on machines with different locales. For example:

```
find("input[type='date']").set("12/31/2016") # works for Canada, fails for America
find("input[type='date']").set("2017-12-31") # works for America, fails for Canada
```

Is it possible to configure Capybara / Selenium to use a specific locale / formatting for inputs? Alternatively is it possible to determine the format of an input via JS and replace with a `page.execute_script` (setting to `input.val(new Date(2016, 12, 31))` doesn't work)?

Comment: Dates in javascript are such a mess that I've got used to using timestamps. Does this topic help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/85116/display-date-time-in-users-locale-format-and-time-offset

Answer (score 2):

The locale/formatting needed for inputs isn't set by Capybara/Selenium, it's set by the browser that's run (Capybara/Selenium don't actually know it's a date box they're filling in, they just send the keystrokes in the order you tell them).  If you only have to deal with a few locales, one idea would be to use `evaluate_script` to get the value of `navigator.language` at the beginning of your specs and then change the format you send dates in based on that.

Comment: Unfortunately the navigator.language doesn't seem to correspond to the formatting of inputs directly. In Canada, I get "en-US".

Comment: @KevinSylvestre Are you using standard HTML date inputs, or are you using a JS widget on them?

Comment: using the standard HTML input (type="date").