# Datetime with t format conversion dd mmm yyyy hh mm ss in java or javascript

Tags: javascript, java, date, datetime-format

I am getting  the date in datetime with t as shown below

```
date1 = "2018-07-14T22:11"
```

I have to convert it into

```
"09 JUL 2018T22:11"
```

I have used

```
String contactDate = (new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy HH")).format(new Date());
```

but it is without time.
I want it with time in `"09 JUL 2018T22:11"` format.

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). Also the modern `LocalDateTime` will parse your string without any explicit formatter.

Comment: I’m a bit surprised that your search and research and attempts didn’t at least bring you a bit closer. You may want to try a bit harder. Also is the month abbreviation required to be in uppercase? Not that it’s impossible.

Comment: If you are using Java 8+ you can use java.time like this `String date = "2018-07-14T22:11";
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(date);

String newDate = ldt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMM yyyy'T'HH:mm", Locale.US));`

Comment: Just to be sure: You are getting July 14 and you want it converted into July 9? Or should it still be July 14, only in the second format given?

Comment: @YCF_L Thanks a lot. But is it necessary to include Locale.US? My form is html contact form on website which could be fill down by users around the world.

Comment: In this case you have to search about [ZonedDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html), beside I add `Locale.US` to show date in English format, for example I run in Frensh system, the date is in Frensh format..

Comment: If you are formatting your date-time for display to a user, you should probably format for that user’s locale. Assuming that the browser knows the locale, see for example [this question: Display date/time in user's locale format and time offset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85116/display-date-time-in-users-locale-format-and-time-offset).

Answer (score 3):

### java.time

```
    DateTimeFormatter newFormatter
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMM uuuu'T'HH:mm", Locale.ENGLISH);
    String date1 = "2018-07-14T22:11";
    LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(date1);
    String contactDate = dateTime.format(newFormatter);
    System.out.println(contactDate);
```

(It’s pretty much what YCF_L already said in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51239624/datetime-with-t-format-conversion-dd-mmm-yyyy-hh-mm-ss-in-java-or-javascript/51240496#comment89458298_51239624).) Output:

> 14 Jul 2018T22:11

**To get the month abbreviation in uppercase, like JUL:** The straightforward and a bit hacky way is:

```
    String contactDate = dateTime.format(newFormatter).toUpperCase(Locale.ENGLISH);
```

With this change the output is:

> 14 JUL 2018T22:11

It only works because the string doesn’t contain any lowercase letters that we want to stay lowercase. To make sure only the month (and nothing else) is converted to uppercase:

```
    Map<Long, String> monthAbbreviations = Arrays.stream(Month.values())
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(m -> Long.valueOf(m.getValue()), 
                    m -> m.getDisplayName(TextStyle.SHORT, Locale.ENGLISH)
                            .toUpperCase(Locale.ENGLISH)));
    DateTimeFormatter newFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendPattern("dd ")
            .appendText(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR, monthAbbreviations)
            .appendPattern(" uuuu'T'HH:mm")
            .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Now we get the desired result without calling `toUpperCase` on the entire result string.

**If you need to subtract 5 days**. I’m not sure you mean it, but you asked for July 9 as a result. Easy when you know how:

```
    dateTime = dateTime.minusDays(5);
```

With this line inserted into my first snippet above I get:

> 09 Jul 2018T22:11

### What went wrong in your code

First, `new Date()` gives the current date and time and ignores the string you got with a future date. Second, your format pattern string contained only hours, not minutes. You need to use lowercase `mm` for minutes as I do in my code.

I do however recommend that you avoid the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API, is so much nicer to work with.

### Link

[Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.

Answer (score 0):

Hi in javascript it's easy just try

`var d = new Date("2018-07-14T22:11");
console.log(d);`

the log will be:

```
Sat Jul 14 2018 22:11:00 GMT+0530
```

you can refer date object in javascript [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_date_object.htm)

Answer (score 0):

In Java you can use:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String datetime = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMM yyyy'T'HH:mm").format(LocalDateTime.now());
    System.out.println(datetime);
}
```

This will print on the console something like:

```
09 Jul 2018T08:07
```

If you want the month to be upper cased you can simply upper case the string:

```
DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMM yyyy'T'HH:mm")
            .format(LocalDateTime.now()).toUpperCase();
```

You can also create a static method to perform this transformation:

```
public static String formatDateTime(LocalDateTime localDateTime) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(localDateTime, "Cannot format null date time");
    return DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMM yyyy'T'HH:mm")
            .format(localDateTime).toUpperCase();
}
```