# Java date format "25 May MON" instead of "25 May Mon" - "d MMM EEE"

Tags: java, kotlin, date, date-formatting, uppercase

Is is possible to format a date like `25 May MON` (not `25 May Mon`)? Or do I have to format the date twice (`"d MMM"` and `"EEE"`), then call `uppercase` for the second string and then join them?

Comment: Personally I would use [`DateTimeFormatterBuilder.appendText(TemporalField, Map<Long, String>)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#appendText(java.time.temporal.TemporalField,java.util.Map)) to build a formatter that would format the day of week abbreviation in all uppercase. But yes, another option is to have two `DateTimeFormatter`s, uppercase the string from one of them and concatenate the results.

Comment: See [my answer to a similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51240496/5772882).

Comment: Yet an alternative would be `String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%te %<tb %<Ta", LocalDate.of(2023, Month.MAY, 25))`. Yields `25 May THU`. Serious downside is it’s about unreadable.

Comment: Is all-uppercase the norm in the particular culture in which you are interested? If so, say so. Then we might be able to get your desired result via `Locale` class.