# How to convert a time to user local timezone in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, time

I am getting this `"2019-05-05T10:30:00Z"` type of time from an API. But I need to convert it like this `"10:30 AM (3:30 PM Your Time)"`. I am using reactJs for my client side. How can I convert the time as user current timezone?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display date/time in user's locale format and time offset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85116/display-date-time-in-users-locale-format-and-time-offset)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```js
const dateToTime = date => date.toLocaleString('en-US', {
  hour: 'numeric',
  minute: 'numeric'
});

const dateString = "2019-05-05T10:30:00Z";
const userOffset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset()*60*1000;
const localDate = new Date(dateString);
const utcDate = new Date(localDate.getTime() + userOffset);

console.log(`${dateToTime(utcDate)} (${dateToTime(localDate)} Your Time)`);
```

Answer (score 2):

take a look at momentjs. it has localization and you can do also custom things.

https://momentjs.com

Comment: Why recommend a whole framework for a relatively simple task?

Comment: this is just a library, also I like it, I use it almost all of my projects. so I  recommend it,  what is wrong with it?

Comment: Unfortunately, Moment's own website recommends against using it as of 2020.

Answer (score 1):

Your API send server DateTime in response, you can just use below function that can convert to your local time zone.

```
function convertUTCDateToLocalDate(date) {
  var dateLocal = new Date(date);
  var newDate = new Date(dateLocal.getTime() - dateLocal.getTimezoneOffset()*60*1000);
  return newDate;
}
```