# Convert JS date format into localized human readable format

Tags: javascript, date

How should I convert a date format of `YYYY-MM-DD` into a human readable format `%e %B %Y` in JS by taking into an account a different language from system's locale?

In PHP it would be like

```php
<?php echo trim(strftime('%e %B %Y', strtotime('2019-07-31'))); ?>
// Renders: 31 July 2019
```

I want to have the same, but with a corresponding language locale, for example "French format" so it will become : **31 Juillet 2019**

==== UPDATED ====

As mention by @Baljinder Singh, solution below from the link, works perfectly

```js
console.log(
  new Date('2019-07-31').toLocaleDateString('fr-FR', {
    year: 'numeric',
    month: 'long',
    day: 'numeric'
  })
)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85116/display-date-time-in-users-locale-format-and-time-offset

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's browser-specific then you can make it dynamic with  `window.navigator.language`.

```js
const date = new Date('2019-07-31').toLocaleDateString(window.navigator.language, {
  year: 'numeric',
  month: 'long',
  day: 'numeric',
});

console.log(date);
```

> **Notice**: Working fine in chrome and firefox.

Comment: *window.navigator.language* is unreliable.

Comment: @RobG why It's unreliable

Comment: If you are dealing with **NodeJS** then you can use `req.headers["accept-language"] `

Comment: It's unreliable because there is no requirement for it to be accurate, so it isn't. Many users are unaware of how to set or alter it. Some browsers do not read it from system settings, and even if they could, it may present a privacy or identity issue so they may not. The best solution is to ask the user, then use an unambiguous form, e.g. always use the month name or abbreviation rather than a number. PS online privacy is becoming a big issue, expect people to want to be as anonymous as possible. If a visitor is using a DE VPN but their browser language is en-NZ, what does that tell you? ;-)

Comment: Docs say: `To use the browser's default locale, pass an empty array.`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```js
let d = new Date('2019-08-20');

let s = d.toLocaleDateString(navigator.languages,{day:"numeric", month:"long", year: "numeric"});

console.log(s);
```