# Highcharts use loal date instead of utc date in tooltip

Tags: javascript, typescript, highcharts

I am using Highcharts and I want that the tooltip content would be displayed as following: `local date : value` (instead of the default format `categorie name : value`) so I used `tooltip.formatter` like this:

```
tooltip: {
   formatter() { 
      return `${Highcharts.dateFormat('%H:%M:%S', +new Date(this.x))}:  <b>
                ${new Intl.NumberFormat().format(this.y)}</b>` 
   }
}
```

The problem now is, that I am displaying local date on the xaxis and now the date on the tooltip is utc date but I want it also to be local date: [see jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4yzw2Ln0/1/).

I cannot use [global.useUTC](https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/global.useUTC) because it is deprecated since v6.0.5.

Is there any way to display the date exactly as date on xaxis so that the tooltip displays : `date : value` (it would be even better if I don't have to use `Highcharts.dateFormat` inside `tooltip.formatter` since the format is not always `'%H:%M:%S'` and it will vary with the provided data) ?

Comment: I think this has been answered in another thread.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85116/display-date-time-in-users-locale-format-and-time-offset

Comment: Hi @Amani Ben Azzouz, the `global.useUTC` option is deprecated because it is moved to `time.useUTC`: https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/time.useUTC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the chart time to format the tooltip:

```js
// Store a reference to the chart
const stockChart = Highcharts.stockChart('container', {

  // ...

  tooltip: {
    formatter() {
      // Use the time object of the chart to format the date
      return `${stockChart.time.dateFormat('%H:%M:%S', +new Date(this.x))}:  <b>${new Intl.NumberFormat().format(this.y)}</b>` 
     }               
   }

  // ...

})
```

[Demo in JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t41Lnpsc/)