# How do I get local time in ISO format in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to convert time in milisecond to my local time in ISO format.

```
let time = 1668268800000
console.log(new Date(time).toISOString())
```

However this do not output my ISO date in my local time.

Comment: I think the definition of ISO is that it's always in UTC. You can manually subtract the timezone difference from the epoch to get what you want though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ISO is UTC by definition. Consider using JS's [internationalization](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat) library to get dates in local format.

You can also do the conversion yourself:

```
let time = 1668268800000
let utcDate = new Date(time)
localTime = time - utcDate.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000
localDate = new Date(localTime)
localIso = localDate.toISOString()
console.log(utcDate.toISOString(), localIso)
```

Comment: Hi there, localIso is the same as utcDate.toISOString()

Comment: Nope, `localIso == utcDate.toISOString()` should yield false, unless your local timezone/system is set to UTC. Here are outputs for me: `utcDate.toISOString(): 2022-11-12T16:00:00.000Z, localIso: 2022-11-12T11:00:00.000Z`. There is a 5hr difference for me locally.

Comment: nvm there was something wrong with my browser. thank you so much!

Comment: no problem, be careful not to shoot yourself in the foot by calling the localIso "true ISO" though later on.

Answer (score 0):

That's correct.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString

> The timezone is always zero UTC offset, as denoted by the suffix Z.

Comment: How do I get that in my local time zone though?

Comment: @Aidenhsy Various ways; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85116/display-date-time-in-users-locale-format-and-time-offset. My preference is https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/.

Comment: I can't use any library unfortunately...

Answer (score 0):

You can create an ISO time string using the Date functions: [`Date.getFullYear()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getFullYear), [`Date.getMonth()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth), [`Date.getDate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate) etc.

Once we have each of these values, we can combine to create the desired ISO string, adding the UTC offset in the format [+-]HH:MM.

This date will be formatted using the local timezone of the client.

```js
function formatUTCOffset(minutes) {
    return (minutes >= 0 ? '+': '-') + (Math.floor(Math.abs(minutes) / 60) + '').padStart(2, '0') + ':' + (Math.abs(minutes) % 60  + '').padStart(2, '0');
}

function formatDateElements(separator, ...elements) {
    return elements.map(x => (x + '').padStart(2, '0')).join(separator);
}

function formatLocalISO(date) {
    let isoDate = formatDateElements('-', date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, date.getDate());
    isoDate += 'T' + formatDateElements(':', date.getHours(), date.getMinutes(), date.getSeconds());
    return isoDate + formatUTCOffset(-date.getTimezoneOffset());
}

let time = 1668268800000
console.log('ISO (1668268800000):', formatLocalISO(new Date(time)))
console.log('ISO (now):          ', formatLocalISO(new Date()))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```