# How do I display a time, date and timezone in the following format in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I need to display the browser local time with time zone in the following format:
'10 Feb 23 10:07:04 EST'

When I do this:

```
new Date(uploadDateTime).toLocaleString('en-US')
```

it displays for me in PST

> 02/10/2023, 10:07:04 AM (Pacific Standard Time)

but my colleague in India sees

> 02/10/2023, 10:07:04 AM (India Standard Time)

It displays wrong format and we need an abbreviation of time zone like PST, IST instead of (Pacific Standard Time).
Also I should not hard code to 'en-US' so it works globally.

I've tried this way:

```
new Date(uploadDateTime).toLocaleString(undefined, { timeZoneName: 'short' })
```

In this case instead of 'en-US' if you put

> undefined

it should default to browser's locale timezone.

Now I see

> 02/10/2023, 10:07:04 AM PST

But in India it shows:

> 02/10/2023, 10:07:04 GMT +5:30

How do I format the date so it shows in the following format in any part of the world?

> 10 Feb 23 10:07:04 EST

Comment: GMT +5:30 is accurate but not the named timezone. This answer is possibly relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54813917/13762301 if you add the `timeZoneName` option. (If I specify `short` I get `GMT +1:00` but if I specify `long` I get `British Summer Time`)